# Android Handler and Thread at start time not running?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, handler, runnable

I'm trying to create a handler at the start of my application so I can have two threads working 1 the UI and 2 my server, I'm doing this so the server will not stop the UI from lagging, and usefully sort out my lag issues, but anyways, I'm looking at this website http://crodrigues.com/updating-the-ui-from-a-background-thread-on-android/ , the guy creates a runnable method, with a run method, there is also a method called updateGame which is always called when that method is ran, now I have tried out his code like so

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final String TAG = gameObject.class.getSimpleName();
//Create a handler to deal with the server
private Handler serverHandler = new Handler();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Turn off title
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    //Make the application full screen
    getWindow().setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView( new gamePanel( this ) );
    Log.d( TAG, "View added" );

    //Server method
    new Thread(new Runnable() { onServer( ); } ).start( );
}

final Runnable updateRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //call the activity method that updates the UI
        updateGame();
    }
};

//Give the positions to the game
public void updateGame()
{
    Log.d(TAG, "Update that game");
}

//Update/run the server
private void onServer()
{
    if( gamePanel.rtnServerState() == true )
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Start the server");
    }

    serverHandler.post( updateRunnable );
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onDestroy()
{
    Log.d( TAG,  "Destroying... " );
    super.onDestroy();
}

public void onStop()
{
    Log.d( TAG,  "Stopping... " );
    super.onStop();
}
}
```

and my updateGame is only ran once. Can anyone see the issue in why it doesn't keep running in the background?

Canvas

Updated post

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final String TAG = gameObject.class.getSimpleName();
private final Handler serverHandler = new Handler();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Turn off title
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    //Make the application full screen
    getWindow().setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView( new gamePanel( this ) );

    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    String message = "hello";
    textView.setText(message);

    Log.d( TAG, "View added" );
    //Server method
    new Thread(new Runnable() { 

    @Override
    public void run() { onServer( ); } } ).start( );
}

private void updateServer()
{
    Log.d(TAG, "testing");
}


//Update/run the server
private void onServer()
{
    if( gamePanel.rtnServerState() == true )
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Start the server");
    }

    serverHandler.post( updateRunnable );
}

//Update/server
final Runnable updateRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public boolean running = true;
    public void run() {
        while(running){
            //call the activity method that updates the UI
            updateServer();
        }
    }
};

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onDestroy()
{
    Log.d( TAG,  "Destroying... " );
    super.onDestroy();
}

public void onStop()
{
    Log.d( TAG,  "Stopping... " );
    super.onStop();
}
}
```

Update number 2

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final String TAG = gameObject.class.getSimpleName();
private final Handler serverHandler = new Handler();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Turn off title
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    //Make the application full screen
    getWindow().setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView( new gamePanel( this ) );

    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    String message = "hello";
    textView.setText(message);

    Log.d( TAG, "View added" );
    //Server method
    Runnable server = new Runnable() {
        public boolean running = true;
        public void run() {
            while(running){
                onServer();  // Make sure this blocks in some way
            }
        }
    };
}

private void updateServer()
{
    Log.d(TAG, "testing");
}


//Update/run the server
private void onServer()
{
    if( gamePanel.rtnServerState() == true )
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Start the server");
    }

    serverHandler.post( updateRunnable );
}

//Update/server
final Runnable updateRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //call the activity method that updates the UI
        updateServer();
    }
};

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onDestroy()
{
    Log.d( TAG,  "Destroying... " );
    super.onDestroy();
}

public void onStop()
{
    Log.d( TAG,  "Stopping... " );
    super.onStop();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Runnable *object*'s `run` method is only called once, after a new Thread is created in response to your `.start()` call.

Usually you do something like:

```
final Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public boolean running = true;
    public void run() {
        while(running){
            doSomething();
        }
    }
};
```

But I'm not sure this is the best way to do this.  The `updateGame()` method will be constantly called unnecessarily.

Instead, put your server logic inside the runnable's `run()` method.  In there use the `while(running){...}` construct I listed above but make sure there is some blocking call in there.  Whether it be from a network socket, a BlockingQueue, etc.  That way it won't needlessly loop.

---

**EDIT**

From discussion in comments.  Leave

```
final Runnable updateRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //call the activity method that updates the UI
        updateGame();
    }
};
```

as it is and change

```
new Thread(new Runnable() { onServer( ); } ).start( );
```

to

```
Runnable server = new Runnable() {
    public boolean running = true;
    public void run() {
        while(running){
            onServer();  // Make sure this blocks in some way
        }
    }
}
new Thread(server).start();
```

Comment: me doing this works fine, but now my UI is frozen, what I'm trying to do is allow the UI thread to run, while this new thread "worker thread" will deal with all the network processing, and hopefully stop my application host lagging, and causing the networking to become 3 seconds delay on packets.

Comment: I edited my post.  Why not just make the "server/network handler" a thread and once it determines that the UI should be updated, call `serverHandler.post( new Runnable(){ updateGame(); } );`

Comment: well at the start the game isn't networked, once a user has pressed on host game, they then become the server, also my updateGame() does nothing, I'm trying to work out how to start a thread for the UI and make a worker thread.

Comment: You don't start a thread for the UI.  Your activity runs on your UI thread.  You only want to start a thread for background activity/ things that would affect the responsiveness of the UI -- like networking.  In current Android APIs, you *must* do this stuff on a different thread or you'll get an Exception when you try to run your app.

Comment: Ok, but when I start this thread, it just locks up my applicatiosn UI, and I can not press on any of the buttons

Comment: What thread?  If you're using the code I provided exactly as is, don't.  I left it there to illustrate how to construct the server Runnable

Comment: The code I post at the start is the same, but my final Runnable is now yours, I understand, I'm going to create a class that will wait for gamePanel variables to change and then a server will be created, but, when i run my code, my application just freezes at the start menu. my code is in my updated post

Comment: My code has no changed, but my Log.d doesn't come up in the log cat console, My code is updated and in my post

Comment: As posted, your code won't even compile: `new Thread(new Runnable() { `

Comment: It does compile because i'm testing on 2.3.6, on my 4.0.3 however yea it doesn't run, but now with this, I'm just asking, if I know make it so my server will run on this thread instead of the UI thread, and of course data from the server thread will be passed to the UI thread and vice-versa, will this stop the application from lagging and stop it from casuing a 3 second delay on sending packets?

Comment: It will absolutely stop the UI from lagging.  It *might* help reduce the packet delay, but can't be sure without seeing the code.

Comment: Ok jewwards, thank you so much for helping me out, I will try and work my way through changing my server code to work on this thread instead, is there by any chance I could get a contact address?

Comment: Jedwards I still have issues with the server not sending out the packets quick enough, I have posted my code in a new question, to clear up all the space http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858561/android-udp-host-has-a-hard-time-passing-data-to-clients

Answer (score 0):

In the tutorial UI is updated only on button click but you do it only once in `onCreate` method. If you will do it in @jedwards way your UI will froze as you wrote. Don't update UI all the time. Try to update it using [timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) or using [sockets](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html). It will be more effective and your UI will not froze.

Timer example

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
...

TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // update UI
    }
};
Timer timer = new Timer();
// 1000 - after 1 second run this timer
// 3000 - and do it every 3 second
timer.schedule(task, 1000, 3000);
```

I wont write socket example because there is to much to write. I've found [this](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/socket-programming/) tutorial where you can read about android socket programming.

BTW Of course you should update only your entity data using socket or timer, not the whole UI.